# Separación de cadena

Tags: java

Tengo una inquietud acerca de como separar una cadena, ya que tengo una variable en la que pueden ingresar nombre y apellidos (hay casos en que puede ser ingresado un nombre y dos apellidos o los 2 nombres y los 2 apellidos).

Si fuesen los 2 nombres y 2 apellidos si tengo una solución el problema es que no siempre voy a tener los 4 datos.

Quisiera contar el no. de espacios para en un bucle for crear los arrays y poder asignarlos para que tengan un valor con el metodo split de la clase String.
Pero no comprendo como hacer el contador para que me cuente los espacios en la cadena que tiene los nombres y apellidos... esto en el caso de que encuentre que tenga un nombre y dos apellidos o que tenga 1 nombre y 1 apellido.

Me pueden ayudar,porfavor.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que sistema usas para recoger los nombres y apellidos?

Comment: como sabrias si son 2 nombre y 1 apellido, o 1 nombre y 2 apellidos?

Comment: tengo campos en que se ingresan nombres y otro para los apellidos y otro campo que es para el resultado de la concatenacion; donde me encuentro todos tienen 2 apellidos

Comment: Capt. Teach todo lo hago mendiante java estoy usando el ide de netbeans

Answer (score 1):

El método que te paso te devuelve una de las siguientes opciones;

```
private int getSpaces(String s) {
    int spaces = 1; // número de espacios, como mínimo 1 (NOMBRE APELLIDO)
    String[] _name = s.split(" ");  // separo el string ingresado
    spaces = _name.length-1;        // número de cadenas a la que le restamos 1 pues tu quieres el número de espacios
    return spaces;      // devuelve el número de espacios de la cadena introducida
}
```

- 1 que se corresponde con NOMBRE APELLIDO
- 2 que se corresponde con NOMBRE1 NOMBRE2 APELLIDO ó NOMBRE APELLIDO1 APELLIDO2
- 3 que se corresponde con NOMBRE1 NOMBRE2 APELLIDO1 APELLIDO2

Después con un simple if puedes obtener el formato;

```
int spaces = getSpaces(s);
    if (spaces == 1) {
        System.out.println("El nombre está en formato 'NOMBRE' 'APELLIDO'");
    } else if (spaces == 2) {
        System.out.println("El nombre está en formato 'NOMBRE1' 'NOMBRE2' 'APELLIDO' o 'NOMBRE' 'APELLIDO1' 'APELLIDO2'");
    } else if (spaces == 3) {
        System.out.println("El nombre está en formato 'NOMBRE1' 'NOMBRE2' 'APELLIDO1' 'APELLIDO2'");
    } else {
        System.out.println("El nombre está en formato incorrecto");
    }
```

Comment: no siempre pueden estar separados espacio(" ") deberias generalizar la función para que envie el caracter por el cual separar. Por ejemplo Juan,Lopez con tu ejemplo devolvera "El nombre esta en formato incorrecto"

Comment: Evidente que en tu ejemplo mi código no funciona, pero el dice en el enunciado que cuente el número de espacios, entiendo que el formato de ingreso del nombre es cadena 'espacio' cadena 'espacio' ....En otro caso como bien dices habría que modificar el código.

Comment: al igual que añades tu variable para contar spaces, puedes aumentar una para el caracter especial